# Error with installing the latest AMD graphics driver in 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, 14.04, intel-graphics

When I was installing the latest AMD graphics beta driver, I found that Ubuntu 14.04 can not load the desktop. After log in the screen only displays the the wallpaper and mouse cursor (mouse cursor can move). My laptop has two graphics cards; `Intel` and `ATI`.

I found an error in `Xorg.0.log`, as stated below:

```
[ 26.033] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 12348
[ 26.033] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 26.033] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 69.30 1366 1404 1426 1436 768 771 777         803 -hsync -vsync (48.3 kHz eP)

[ 26.033] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 46.20 1366 1404 1426 1436 768 771 777   803 -hsync -vsync (32.2 kHz e)
[ 150.658] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.1 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none

[ 150.675] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[ 155.931] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm

[ 157.521] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm
[ 157.536] (EE) Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm

[ 159.422] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 182.925] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.1 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none

[ 182.946] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[ 183.055] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm

[ 183.072] (EE) Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-992DCD2811F9928D990F91F3229E52A1EC62B72A.xkm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it this way:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save your file and run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Let me know if it works for you

Comment: I have try as you say but the error is still there,could you please   explain why this happen

Comment: This happens because you must use only one of the graphics cards. Go to the BIOS and deactivate one of the graphics cards (use ATI, by experience it is better)

Comment: yes,when I close the Intel graphics card ,I can log in the systerm normal. But in that way ,I can only use the ATI card.I want to use the Intel card only,could you tell me how to close the ATI card,the BIOS of my computer do not support.

Comment: the vgaswitcheroo is not working on 14.04,that's why I am try to install the ATI driver to switch graphics cards

Comment: Just look for it yourself in the BIOS, I can not tell you because I do not know the version of your BIOS and so on. You will find something like 'Enable' , 'Disable'